# Unsigned char pointer pointing to an unsigned char array

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make an array of unsigned char's and make a pointer which points to the first position of the array but I keep getting an error. This is my code as well as the error:

```
void initBuffer
{
      unsigned char buffer[size];
      unsigned char *ptr;
      ptr = &buffer;
}
```

[image]

I suspect it's a very simple type error buy I'm new to C and not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The error you're showing is not correlated to the code you've pasted.

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions, and that includes build logs and error output.

Comment: Also make sure to show a proper [mre] that causes the error.

Comment: @aybe my apologies, that was the original screen shot of the error, I've since changed some variable names

Comment: please make sure that your errors and code match. this one does not.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `&buffer` is `unsigned char (*)[size]`.

The type of `ptr` is `unsigned char *`.

Those two types are *not* the same. Just as the compiler tells you.

Assuming you want to make `ptr` point to the first elements of `buffer` then you need to use `&buffer[0]` which has the correct type. And that's what plain `buffer` will *decay* to:

```
ptr = buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a minor change to the code you provided, ptr = &buffer[0];

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
      unsigned char buffer[] = {'A','B','C','D'};
      unsigned char *ptr;
      ptr = &buffer[0];    // ptr, points to first element of array
      for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
          printf("%c", ptr[i]);
      return 0;
}
```